# How to download the SSL certificate from a website using PowerShell?

Tags: ssl, powershell, ssl-certificate, openssl

I want to download an SSL certificate using PowerShell

I glad for any help

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I thoght that it's very simple like as bash @Crypt32

Comment: Since this is also tagged `openssl` you can use it to download the certificate list with `openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 -showcerts`. Leaving it up to you to integrate this into PowerShell.

Comment: Can't comment yet, but seems answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233702/how-to-download-the-ssl-certificate-from-a-website-using-powershell